# curl doesnt retrieve a response

Tags: php

```
$c=  curl_init('https://disqus.com/api/3.0/threads/listPosts.json?api_key=EqGFOM4KaZaVb7TuhzxeiCeHBqwOfUHZ5YIih5Al51Fj8p410zsSAFaowG7Tafv5&thread:ident=2&forum=bestcamdirectory&limit=1');
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response=  curl_exec($c);
   echo $response;
       curl_close($c);
```

The problem is that nothing is obtained from the server. I could use file_get_Contents..but my server disallows using it.. whats the reeason that no response is obtained

Comment: what does `curl_error` say? what's the error?

Comment: I got the response with your code.

Comment: I got no response..you could put the code and test it.. what response did you get xdazz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling a "https" site, so you will probably have to set the `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to false.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
```

Comment: hmm.. nice ..that was the problem..didnt notice i used https..thanks